# Get Marketing Cloud UserID (numeric)

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, ampscript, user, landing-page

I'm currently following this guide:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/createDataExtension.htm

To create a data extension via a landing page.

It works, but I'm stuck at the part where you have to provide ClientID to add data retention settings to the DE. You have to provide ClientID and UserID:

```
SET @client = CreateObject("ClientID")
SetObjectProperty(@client, "ID", @memberID)
SetObjectProperty(@client, "UserID", @userIDwithPermission)
```

The guide says I can get the UserID by hovering over a name in the Users list, but there seems to be no such option. I get a very long string, instead of a numeric UserID. I tried using the Username but it returns this error:

> Error Message:    Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to
>   type 'System.Int32'.

So clearly I'm looking for a number rather than a string. How on earth do I find UserID?

Answer (score 0):

I asked around, and I believe you're looking at antiquated documentation.  I don't believe we publicly expose UserID any more.  I will get this page on the backlog.

Comment: That's correct, the User ID can only be printed via an "Authenticated Microsite Page" using the option "System Authenticated Redirection" - I don't think this is available anymore and has been replaced with CloudPages which offer less functionality.